New Zealand tourist visa application for parents (India)
My mother is traveling with me to NZ and she's retired and hence depending on me. Given that the visa application only allows the addition of children and partners in the same application, I am guessing I will have to create another login for her and fill out another application form.
How do I link her application with mine given that I will be the primary sponsor? Unfortunately both Google and ChatGPT have proven unhelpful.

Do you get a reference number when you apply?

yessir, i did .. so i am guessing linking this reference number should work ?

ok, so after calling multiple numbers here's what Indian's ( or non visa-waived country citizens ) need to do, do include anyone else they are sponsoring ( partner and dependent children can be included in the same application ).
You will need to upload cover letters cross referencing each others application ( using the unique application ID ) and while uploading the financial documents you can upload the same set of docs for the sponsored person ( mother, in my case ) AND mention the same in the cover letter.
Let me now go ahead and do this. I shall update this thread once i get an accept from the consulate.
